# Duality Between Semilattices and Totally Disconnected locally Compact Hausdorff Spaces

Tags: general-topology, operator-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, semigroups, locales

On page 18 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.05940.pdf) paper, the author states that there is a duality (correspondence?) between semilattices (i.e., abelian semigroups of idempotents) and totally disconnected locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Given a semilattice $E$, consider the space of characters

$$\widehat{E} := \{\chi : E \to \{0,1\} \mid \chi \neq 0 \text{ semigroup homomorphism} \}.$$

equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence. From what I gather, the topology of pointwise convergence on $\widehat{E}$ is the topology it inherits in virtue of being a subspace of the topological space $\{0,1\}^{E}$. Since $\{0,1\}^{E}$ is totally disconnected and Hausdorff (a product of totally disconnected spaces is totally disconnected; same is true for Hausdorffness), $\widehat{E}$ is also totally disconnected and Hausdorff. Moreover, $\{0,1\}^E$ is compact and therefore locally compact (compact Hausdorff spaces are locally compact).

However, I am having trouble showing that $\widehat{E}$ is locally compact. Also, what about the other direction. If one starts with a totally disconnected locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, how does one construct a semilattice?

Comment: So $E$ has an operation $\cdot$ that is Abelian, has a $1$ and obeys $x^2=x$ for all $x$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, that's right.

Comment: Maybe you can show that $\hat{E}$ is open in $\{0,1\}^E$ in the product topology? It must be an intersection of a closed set and an open set, and being a semigroup homomorphism is a "closed condition".

Comment: Isn't $\widehat E$ closed in $\{0,1\}^E$? Take $f\in \{0,1\}^E\setminus\widehat E$ so that there are $x,y\in E$ with, $f(x)=0$, $f(y)=1$ and $f(xy)=1$ (this covers all possibilities, I think, except for $f=0$). Then $\langle xy,1\rangle\cap \langle x,0\rangle\cap\langle y,1\rangle$ is a neighbourhood of $f$ disjoint from $\widehat E$ (here $\langle a,\epsilon\rangle=\{g:E\rightarrow\{0,1\}\mid g(a)=\epsilon\}$ are the pointwise subasic open sets).

Comment: There might be a subtly at $f=0$. Either $\widehat E$ is finite and closed, or $E$ is infinite and its closure in $\{0,1\}^E$ is $\widehat E\cup\{0\}$ (because every finite intersection of subbasic open neighbourhoods of $0$ contains some nonzero homomorphism). In the first case there is nothing to more to say. In the second, $\widehat E$ is open subset of its closure, and so is locally compact as a locally closed subset of $\{0,1\}^E$.

Comment: @Tyrone I actually tried showing that it is closed via nets, but I couldn't get the argument to work. So, $\widehat{E}$ is actually compact and the statement can be strengthened. But I still wonder about the other direction.

Comment: @user193319 see my addendum. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the material in Li's paper. Doesn't the reverse direction imply that every totally disconnected $T_2$ space embeds in a Cantor cube? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Tyrone Every zero-dimensional Hausdorff space does embed in a Cantor cube, not every totally disconnected one. But for LCH spaces these notions are the same.

Comment: Thank you, @HennoBrandsma, I found what I was missing :). Given a zero-dimensional LCH space $X$, doesn't this proceed by choosing a clopen base $\mathcal{B}$ and embedding $X$ into $\{0,1\}^\mathcal{B}$ by $x\mapsto (\chi_U(x))_{U\in\mathcal{B}}$, where $\chi_U$ is the characteristic function of $U$? The $\chi_U$'s are idempotent, so doesn't this give the required construction? Maybe make it canonical by taking $\mathcal{B}$ to be the family of all clopen subsets of $X$?

Comment: Yes that would work. Seeing points of $E$ as "tuples" of $0$-$1$ is the way to go. Cantor cubes are topological Boolean groups, so the only thing to check is that the embedding via characteristic functions is a sub-semigroup, and that is quite easy. The whole result isn't that deep. @Tyrone

Comment: @user193319: This seems closely related with [Stone representation theorem of Boolean algebra.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras)